# Drag and drop files onto batch script shortcut in Windows 11

Tags: batch, windows-11, drag-and-drop, file-shortcut

I frequently need to process a bunch of files with a batch script. The way I usually do this is by selecting the files in the explorer and then drag-and-dropping them onto a shortcut to the script (the target of that shortcut is `cmd /C C:\path\to\my\script.bat`).

Currently I have a copy of that shortcut in every directory where I have files that need to be processed by that script, but I would prefer to have that shortcut in one location and be able to drag-and-drop the files to be processed onto it quickly. One possible location is the desktop, which allows me to select and start dragging the files in the explorer, hit <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>, and drop them onto the shortcut, but then all applications are minimized, and I have to restore them individually.

Ideally, I would like to have that shortcut pinned to the taskbar and simply drag-and-drop the files onto there. However, while Windows 11's 22H2 update restored drag-and-drop via the taskbar for applications that are already running, it seems that there is no way to drag-and-drop files onto a shortcut to trigger execution of its target command. The same applies to the start menu, I can pin the shortcut there, but I cannot drag-and-drop anything onto it.

Another option would be to pin that shortcut to the explorer's Quick Access menu (I can drag-and-drop files onto a directory in the Quick Access menu to move them to that directory), but it seems only directories can be pinned there.

Since I am out of ideas, I would like to ask for suggestions as to how to circumvent the limited drag-and-drop functionality in Windows 11 for such a use case.
Specifically: Is there a convenient location for a batch script shortcut (or actually any shortcut that executes a command with filenames passed as arguments) which is easily accessible to quickly drag-and-drop files onto it?

Comment: Does it have to be drag&drop? I usually use the SendTo menu for this usecase (simply add a shortcut to the script to %APPDATA%\Microsoft\Windows\SendTo, and use right-click, select Send To, select the script name to execute)

Comment: As @Paul suggests, *Send To* is a convenient two-step use of the context menu. You could even add the batch file to the context menu for single-click selecction: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20449316/how-add-context-menu-item-to-windows-explorer-for-folders

Comment: @Paul Thanks, that is helpful. I previously tried to add the shortcut to the "Open with" menu, which prompted the error message "The program you have selected cannot be associated with this file type. Please choose another program." With SendTo it works.